# CoSign API: Controlling the font size in the signature block

Tags: digital-signature, cosign-api

Is there any way to control the font size in a signature field when a user signs a document using the web service?

I'm referring specifically to the name, title and date attributes--as well as their respective labels--and not the graphical signatures.

In the [API Guide](http://www.arx.com/files/DOCUMENTS/SAPI-Signature-API-v6.2-Programmer-Guide.pdf) -- under Appendix C: SAPI ENUMS Part II: SAPICrypt -- I see `SAPI_ENUM_CONF_ID_PDF_FONT_SIZE`. But it looks like this is specific to SAPICrypt and not the SAPI Web Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SAPI_ENUM_CONF_ID_PDF_FONT_SIZE` is not in use (the API Guide states this parameter is reserved for feature use). The font size is defined by the size of the signature field.